# How to append list of 2 files in 2 directories

Tags: linux

I have 2 directories `dir1` and `dir2` which has same set of file names like

```
dir1 
    file1(1 2 3)
    file2
    file3 ....
dir2
    file1(4 5 6)
    file3
    file5 ....
```

Now I want to append `dir1/file1` to `dir2/file1`, `dir1/file3` to `dir2/file3`

I need to append only if both files are present in 2 different directories.
here `dir1/file2` is not in `dir2`, so we need to ignore those cases.

The final output should be `file1(1 2 3 4 5 6)` like this.

Comment: the last sentence is misleading: what is file1(1 2... 6)? From the first part I understand that dir2/file1 should now have dir1/file1 after it.

Comment: maybe you can simply use `>>`: loop over all files in dir1, extract the filename part, and execute `cat dir1/$FILENAME >> dir2/$FILENAME`. Or do you want to completely ignore files not in dir2?

Comment: I just given an example like dir1/file1 may have 1 2 3 and dir2/file1 may have 4 5 6 and after append the dir2/file1 should have 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: Thx Karsten :-) I had tried in tht way but had some confusion ..So i thought of asking if there is any inbuilt command or other better way

Answer (score 0):

> I want to append `dir1/file1` to `dir2/file1`, `dir1/file3` to
>   `dir2/file3`

```
files=`ls dir1`
cd dir2
files=`ls $files 2>/dev/null`
for file in $files
do  cat ../dir1/$file >>$file
done
```

Note that since you *append `dir1/file1` to `dir2/file1`*, `dir2/file1` has `4 5 6` `1 2 3`.